# Can not access a subclass method from a superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I was doing my Object Oriented Programming homework and i stuck somewhere. We were basically told to do a phonebook. It has a PhoneNumber class which extends ContactInfo class. There is also a PhoneBookEntry class that contains an ArrayList of ContactInfo objects.
In the PhoneBookEntry class there has to be a method called displayPhoneNumbers(). And homework says: 
**displayPhoneNumbers(): Prints all PhoneNumbers in the contactInfos.**
 Well, to display a phone number i have to be able to access to a PhoneNumber object but all i have in the PhoneBookEntry class is a list of ContactInfo objects which can not have a phone number in it.

```
public class PhoneBookEntry {
    private String name;
    ArrayList<ContactInfo> contactInfos;

    public PhoneBookEntry(){
        contactInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void displayPhoneNumbers(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= contactInfos.size(); i++) {
            //Error
            System.out.println(contactInfos.get(i).getNumber());
        }         
    }
}   

public abstract class ContactInfo {
    String contactName;

    public ContactInfo(String contactName){
        this.contactName=contactName;
    }

    abstract void displayContact();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Since the ContactInfo class has no getNumber() method, i cant access and print it. Am i missing something here or is something wrong with the homework?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question (but with part of the question instead of code)

Comment: i think you have to add a property for the phonenumbers to the ContactInfo-Class - as well as for the emailadresses